# Have 4 DateTimes, need newest

Tags: php, datetime

I have 4 DateTimes:

```
$article->getCreated();
$article->getChanged();
$article->getTimestamp();
$article->getImage()->getTimestamp();
```

I have a method like:

```
public function getLatestUpdate(\Article $article) { }
```

Sometimes my brain has a rather high latency and I don't get a good solution that quick.
I could just put in some `if` clauses but I want a better way to `return` **the newest of those DateTime values**.

Can I use `sort()` on DateTimes?

Is there a one liner?

Comment: Why don't you keep $article->getChanged() up to date. And if $image gets updated, or something else.., update $changed of $article..

Comment: @Brice I need to compare article and image and they both have their own `updated` timestamp. There are in fact more than 4 TimeStamps on different Objects and Entities

Comment: I honestly think that it's not a good practice. Updating any field of the article should update the `updated` field of the article. Let's say in the future you add `$article->getVideo()`, you really want to update `getLatestUpdate()`? Anyway that's my opinion. The answers below should solve it for you:)

Comment: It's all cool. `getChanged` updates itself by Doctrine but `image` and `article` are different entities that for a special case I need to compare their `changed` field. Both get updated automatically tho

Answer (score 1):

If you could have the dates in an array, you could then return the [max](https://www.php.net/max) value:

```
$timestamps = array(
    $article->getCreated(),
    $article->getChanged(),
    $article->getTimestamp(),
    $article->getImage()->getTimestamp()
);

return max($timestamps);
```

or for your one liner:

```
return max($article->getCreated(), $article->getChanged(), $article->getTimestamp(), $article->getImage()->getTimestamp());
```

(although I think it's more readable with the array).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`min()`](https://www.php.net/min) or [`max()`](https://www.php.net/max) :

```
$min = min($article->getCreated(), $article->getChanged(), $article->getTimestamp(), $article->getImage()->getTimestamp());

// or

$max = max($article->getCreated(), $article->getChanged(), $article->getTimestamp(), $article->getImage()->getTimestamp());
```

Answer (score 0):

If all dates at timestamp you can create an array and get `max` value it should be the last update time.

Answer (score 0):

The newest datetime will always be the largest number. The newer a timestamp is, the larger it will be. Look at:

```
strtotime($datetime);
```

and you'll see your date time string represented as a Unix timestamp.